# Extended Leaf error

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

i try to domain many2one field in , but give error  Invalid field 'batch_id.id' in leaf:

my code like this :

```
batch_id=fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.batch',domain="[('batch_id.id','=',37)]")
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the domain we always pass/use the  field of associated model.

For example if i have to use domain on `name` and `lst_price` of `product.product` the code will be something  like:

```
product_id=fields.Many2one('product.product',domain="[('name','=','test'),('lst_price','>=',100)]")
```

I your case just use **id** instead of ***batch_id.id***:

```
batch_id=fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.batch',domain="[('id','=',37)]")
```

Hope this may help in your case.

Comment: For that little that was given in the question, i would say your answer is correct.

Comment: Hi @CZoellner  thanks for your appreciation  .it's sound silly but can i ask for help in odoo runbot

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "help in odoo runbot"?

Comment: i am just following this link http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-and-configuring-your-own-runbot/

Comment: Oh ok, sorry i can't help you with configuring an odoo runbot. I never did that before by myself ;-) Instead try to write YENTHE666 a question on that topic. If there is no possibility on his site try github, i saw him somewhere around there ;-)

Comment: hi @PrakashSharma , i want to search batch id in culling list ids ,